# JButton with icon and text but hide text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

For automatic test purposes is a must to have the text set because is the identification used by robot to navigate though screens.
I need to create a `JButton` with text and icon but only show the icon.

I have tried several things:

1. use of `setHideActionText(true)`:

   ```
   jButton button = new JButton(icon);
   jButton.setHideActionText(true);
   jButton.setText(_messageManager.getMessage(messageKey));
   ```
2. `setHoritzontalTextPosition`
3. `setVerticalAlignment`

but none worked.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: fix the test environment: it's broken (as you experience :-) if you are not able to test an icon-only label/button. Adding hacks just for sake of that broken test tool detoriates the code. For identification, it should use either a name or a client property

Comment: Rather the using the text, every JComponent can have a name

Comment: @keopatra has the trick, changed the automatic test to use the name and set an unique name for each button in system.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to create a JButton with text and icon but only show the icon.

You could have possibly used [setActionCommand()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)

```
jButton.setActionCommand("Button 1");
```

Or, you may also use [setName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)

```
jButton.setName("Button 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the text only in the test environment but not in production?

Then you could so something like this:

```
setText("");
if(test)
   setText("sometext");
```

Comment: the test is executed like it was in production, there is an automatic environment that compiles and generates the binary and the test automatically takes it, so this code is not possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the size of the Font of the button text to 0.
And if that does not work, set the size to the lowest possible value and the color of the text equal to the background color of the button (you might have to tweak the layout a little afterwards ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the text of the JButton completely if your work with the TooltipText:

```
   jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/money.png")));
   jButton1.setToolTipText("Foo");  
   ....
   jButton1.getToolTipText(); // use instead of getText()
```

Comment: The automatic test was already done to use identify the text value of the button component so I cannot use this idea, but was a good one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Button text not shown with painted icons!

The code:

```java
        Icon icon = new PlayIcon();
        JButton play = new JButton("PlayIcon with text", icon);
```

You expect a text with the button. But it is not shown!
Maybe your icon paints itsself like this:

```java
public class PlayIcon implements Icon ...

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(color==null ? c.getForeground() : color);
        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(x + 2, y + 2);
        path.lineTo(x + width - 2, y + height / 2);
        path.lineTo(x + 2, y + height - 2);
        path.lineTo(x + 2, y + 2);
        g2d.fill(path);
        g2d.dispose(); // <===========
...
```

Then the problem is the `dispose()` call in the `PlayIcon` class.
Remove it!

[The result will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OR6P.png)

See: [github issue](https://github.com/homebeaver/SwingSet/issues/19)